# search a word in webview android using findAll

Tags: java, android

I have this part of code to search in a webview a word user types...

```
findBox = findViewById(R.id.findBox);
        findBox.setSingleLine(true);
        findBox.setOnKeyListener((v, keyCode, event) -> {
            if ((event.getAction() == KeyEvent.ACTION_UP) || ((keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_ENTER)))
            {
                myWebView.findAll(findBox.getText().toString());

                try
                {
                    // Can't use getMethod() as it's a private method
                    for (Method m : MainActivity.class.getDeclaredMethods())
                    {
                        if (m.getName().equals("setFindIsUp"))
                        {
                            m.setAccessible(true);
                            m.invoke(myWebView, true);
                            break;
                        }
                    }
                }
```

It is working but android studio show findAll is deprecated as of API 16. Any ideas how to solve?

Comment: use findAllAsync

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try using -->

```
myWebView.findAllAsync(findBox.getText().toString());
```